# How to take zero from the decimal part?

Tags: c#

I have a senario where I am converting numbers to words and I have suceeded in it, but I found one scenario where it's not working. If I enter the number as "**10**", it displays "**ten**". Also, "**10.2**" will display "**ten point two**". However, if I enter "**10.0**" it will not display as "**ten point zero**".

For seperating the whole number part from the decimal part I usually split the number by '**.**', but if I enter a number like "**10.0**", the string array will contain only "**10**" and not the "**0**"

The spitting part which I have done is given below:

```
string[] number = Convert.ToString(context.NumberToTranslate).Split('.');
```

Comment: What is the type of NumberToTranslate?

Comment: Be sure to use Decimal.TryParse() to convert your input to a number.  The Decimal type preserves trailing zeros.  There is no solution if NumberToTranslate is of type double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Febin:

It seems like an order of operations issue. Try doing the splitting before the converting"

```
var parts = ("10.0").Split('.'); //or context.NumberToTranslate

parts[0] //"10"
parts[1] //"0"

//Convert
string[] number = Convert.ToString(parts);
```

You don't have to break it out completely, but I did that to show you can split "10.0" and *then* do what you want with it.

Comment: you are already taking the Number as a string, so obviously splitting will work.. but here the OP is using a Real number and converting it to string for splitting.

Answer (score 5):

To test if your number is an integer w/o decimal point you could try and parse it with

```
int tmpInt;
bool isInteger = Int32.TryParse(num.ToString(), out tmpInt);
```

If it is an integer just convert the number to your string representation otherwise preserve the digit after the decimal point no matter what using a custom format string:

```
 string number = num.ToString("#.0");
```

The same issue can arise if your number is less than 1, so you can use the zero placeholder for the digit before the decimal point as well:

```
 string number = num.ToString("#0.0");
```

Also see [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: but this will only work for 1 digit after decimal point not more that that.. like `(10.01).ToString("#.0")` will give `10.0` only.. so not the perfect solution. Also it will do rounding too

Comment: @Shekar_Pro: Yes, I guess you would have to know with how many digits you want to work with, that's a drawback

Answer (score 3):

Actually numbers after point is lost if the number, even i the number is a Float or Double.
The solution is to use **decimal** Type for these numbers, it **preserves the 0** after decimal.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(10.0M));
```

Output:

```
10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is compare your number to itself cast to an integer to determine if you need to append zero to the string that you're generating.

Something along the lines of:

```
var n = 10.0f;
if(n == (int)n) {
   Console.WriteLine("zero"); 
}
```